# Detect browser support for image type in canvas.toDataURL

Tags: html, canvas, base64, data-uri

I am trying to get dataUrl from `<canvas>` element using `canvas.toDataURL()`. By default, it returns `image/png`, but some browsers support the `image/jpeg` filetype.

How can i detect if a browser supports `image/jpeg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just specify that you want JPEG like this:

```
var quality = 0.8;
var dataUri = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality); // quality is optional
```

If your dataUri now contains the same string JPEG is supported. Otherwise the string will be image/png.

```
if (dataUri.match('image/jpeg')) {
    // support jpeg
}
```

That being said, I don't think there is any browser which do *not* support the jpeg format. A test like this is better suited for more uncommon formats in various degrees such as webp, bitmap etc.

For a general test you could do:

```
function hasSupport(mime) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = canvas.height = 1;
    var uri = canvas.toDataURL(mime);
    return (uri.match(mime) !== null);
}
```

Comment: yeah i know that but i want to know that if browser supports it or not ? Or in other way is there any harm if i used it & browser doesn't support this in dataurl

Comment: @Peeyush you could make a small off-screen canvas 1x1 pixel and grab the data uri as in the answer and test the returned string if it matches the provided string. That could be an efficient way of testing support.

Comment: @Peeyush the browser will always fallback to PNG if the format isn't supported so there is no harm.

Answer (score 0):

Per the HTML5 spec at https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-canvas-element:

> When trying to use types other than "image/png", authors can check if
>   the image was really returned in the requested format by checking to
>   see if the returned string starts with one of the exact strings
>   "data:image/png," or "data:image/png;". If it does, the image is PNG,
>   and thus the requested type was not supported. (The one exception to
>   this is if the canvas has either no height or no width, in which case
>   the result might simply be "data:,".)

Therefore you can check like this:

```
var type = 'image/jpeg';
var data = canvas.toDataUrl(type);

if ( /^data:image\/png[,;]/.test(data) ) {
  type='image/png';
} else if ( /^data:,/.test(data) ) {
  type = null; 
}
```