# How can I find which encodings are available to toDataURL()

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a web page that allows the user to extract an image from inside a canvas on that page.  I do this using `canvas.toDataURL(type, encoderOption)`.  Currently I always create the image as png, but I have been asked to offer the user a choice of formats such as `png`, `jpeg` etc.

Form what I have read all browsers should support `png` but other encodings are optional.  Is there a way that I can find out at runtime what encodings the user's browser supports so that I can show a select for the user to choose their preferred format?

Comment: So basically need to detect image formats supported by a browser isn't, correct me if am wrong

Comment: If you have access to the server the easiest solution would be to check the [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header for the [MIME-types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Image_types). For PHP this will be the `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']` variable

Comment: @DILEEP I need a way to offer a list of valid encodings to the user.  I don't want to allow the user to choose an encoding an then find that I can't create an image with that encoding.

Comment: @Reyno - the image is being created in as a data url in the browser, there will be no server access involved.  What what MIME-type header should I be looking at?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect browser support for image type in canvas.toDataURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340752/detect-browser-support-for-image-type-in-canvas-todataurl)

Comment: Hi Doan, thanks for that.  I know that you can try a particular encoding and find out if it works or not.  What I want to avoid is offering an encoding option to the user and then it failing when they try it.  It looks bad.  I wondered if there is a way to find out in advance what is supported rather than finding out afterwards when it fails (i.e. produces a png when the user asked for something else).